# File info of deleted file and file timestamps in node, chokidar

Tags: node.js, websocket, fs, chokidar

I have started learning node file system and have created a simple file app using websocket, chokidar and node. I am trying to show the files activity in current directory and it's working fine when I modified somet files but with couple of issues.

1. deleted file (unlink event chokidar): Getting error when unlink and try to read file info using fs.stats. Is there any workaround because node unable to read stat of file which isn't exist?
2. atime, mtime, ctime, birthtime are same when make any changes in file under directory. is there any way (or module) to get rename, file content change and file deleted details (screenshot below)?

*Note: I am on window 10*

**question title is weird, suggestions are welcome.**

[image]

Comment: I am trying to read the data from recently deleted files using chokidar. Chokidar's 'unlink' event fires with 'file' and 'stat' parameters - but what can you do with 'file' if nodejs if filesystem 'fs' can't see it??